# how to build expression tree for multiple level reference property(linked property)?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, expression-trees

For example, let's say i have a string property "Document.DocumentType.DocumentCode" with DocumentCode is a nullable decimal type.

How can I build an expression tree for this: `x.Document.DocumentType.DocumentCode.GetValueOrDefault() == 4`?

For my real case, I won't know exactly what the linked string property will look like or the levels of properties.

Comment: I would suggest rewriting this, not very easy to understand what the actual question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that tree is:

- An equality match, where the left hand side is complicated and the right hand side is a constant expression 4.
- The LHS is a method call `GetValueOrDefault()` on (an expression)
- The expression from the previous step is a property access expression `DocumentCode` on (an expression)
- The expression from the previous step is a property access expression `DocumentType` on (an expression)
- The expression from the previous step is a property access expression `Document` on a `ParameterExpression`

Start from the bottom, and build it up from there. In other words, if you know you're only going to have properties, you'll want to:

- Split the string by "."
- Create a `ParameterExpression`
- Loop round the set of properties, adding another layer or property access each time, e.g.

  ```
  currentExpression = Expression.Property(currentExpression, propertyName);
  ```
- Add a method call at to the expression
- Build an equality comparison using that and whatever constant value you're given